# Error in FROM syntax clause

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm trying to execute this code but I keep getting an error in my query

```
string str = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Main database.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=123456";            

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(str);

string query = "SELECT[Total price],[Parameter change] FROM [Firebird m0 Damage]='" + comboBox6.Text + "' ";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);

OleDbDataReader dbr;

try
{
    con.Open();

    dbr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while(dbr.Read())
    {
           string me = (string) dbr["[Total price]"];
           textBox15.Text = me;
    }
}
catch(Exception es)
{
    MessageBox.Show(es.Message);
}
```

I tried executing this query and it also failed

```
select * 
from [Total price],[Parameter change] 
where [Firebird m0 Damage]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: From should be a table name, not column names. Column names go between the select and the from

Answer (score 1):

If you *format out* your query in order to make it *readable* (thanks to `@""` strings in C#)

```
string query = 
  @"SELECT [Total price],
           [Parameter change]  
      FROM [Firebird m0 Damage]='" + comboBox6.Text + "'";
```

you'll see that `FROM` is *completely wrong* as DBMS says to you.
Probably, you want something like that:

```
string query = 
  @"SELECT [Total price],
           [Parameter change]  
      FROM [Firebird m0] 
     WHERE [Damage] = '" + comboBox6.Text + "'"; // looks that you want "WHERE"
```

If it's your case, you can write a better *parametrized* SQL

```
string query = 
  @"SELECT [Total price],
           [Parameter change]  
      FROM [Firebird m0] 
     WHERE [Damage] = ?";
```

and pass `comboBox6.Text` as a *parameter*.

And the code will be something like that:

```
...
// Put IDisposable into using
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(str)) {
  con.Open();

  // Make SQL being readable
  string query = 
    @"SELECT [Total price],
             [Parameter change]  
        FROM [Firebird m0] 
       WHERE [Damage] = ?"; 

  // Put IDisposable into using
  using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con)) {
    cmd.Parameters.Add(comboBox6.Text);

    // Put IDisposable into using
    using (OleDbDataReader dbr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
      if (dbr.Read()) // You don't need "while" just "if"
        textBox15.Text = Convert.ToString(dbr["[Total price]"]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing table name and where clause in your query..

```
string query = "SELECT[Total price],[Parameter change] FROM [TableName] Where [Firebird m0 Damage]='" + comboBox6.Text + "' ";
```